# python __slots__ descriptor getter/setter

Tags: python, python-2.7

The [documentation on `__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#notes-on-using-slots) says they're "implemented as descriptors." Is it possible to customize the getters/setters for descriptors created via `__slots__`? Can I do something like

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ['a']
    def __init__(self, a):
        self._a = a
        
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a.title()
        
    @a.setter
    def a(self, x):
        if len(x) == 10:
            self._a = x
        else:
            raise ValueError('incorrect length!')
            
    @a.deleter
    def a(self):
        self._a = ''
```

ETA: Only semi-relatedly, the `self._a = a` bit above would mean that the initial value of `a` wouldn't be run through the setter. Is there a way to  pass the value into the setter on `__init__` as well?

---

ETA2: So based on [Bi Rico's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30585677/1368008), I worked out this:

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ('_a',)
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._a = self.validate_a(x)
        
    @staticmethod
    def validate_a(x):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            return x
        else:
            raise ValueError(':(')
            
    @property
    def a(self):
        return str(self._a)
    
    @a.setter
    def a(self, x):
        self._a = self.validate(x)
        
    @a.deleter
    def a(self):
        self._a = 0
```

The separate `validate_a` method solves my 'add-on' question about treating the value(s) passed into `__init__` the same as values passed in through the setter (and as such isn't necessary if you don't want to do that.)

It feels a little hacky to only put 'dummy' var names in `__slots__` (i.e., `Foo._a` only exists for the benefit of the `Foo.a` property), but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your code almost works as is; the only changes you need to make are

```
__slots__ = ['_a']  # _a instead of a
def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a  # a instead of _a
```

If for some reason you really want to avoid the separate `_a` slot and `a` wrapper, you can replace the default slot descriptor with your own descriptor, but I wouldn't recommend it. Also, the replacement has to happen after the class is created:

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ['a']

underlying_descriptor = Foo.a

@property
def a(self):
    return underlying_descriptor.__get__(self, Foo).title()

@a.setter
def a(self, x):
    if len(x) == 10:
        underlying_descriptor.__set__(self, x)
    else:
        raise ValueError('incorrect length!')

@a.deleter
def a(self):
    underlying_descriptor.__del__(self)

Foo.a = a
```

You might try to simplify all that `underlying_descriptor` stuff by setting `Foo._a = Foo.a` and accessing it through `self._a`, but then you have an `_a` attribute on your objects, and the whole point of this version is to avoid the second attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to list properties in `__slots__` only attributes, if you change slots to `__slots__ = ['_a']`, your class will work as expected.

#### Update

Sorry I didn't see you add-on question in my first read through. Having a static validate method is fine, but you don't need to call it explicitly in the in `__init__`, instead set `self.a` directly, only use `self._a` when you want to intentionally bypass the setter/getter.

I don't know what you mean by,

> It feels a little hacky to only put 'dummy' var names in `__slots__`

`a` is a property of the class (which btw is also implemented using descriptors) so if you also include it in `__slots__` you're instructing the class to create two conflicting descriptors for the same thing.

`_a` is an attribute of the class so if you're using `__slots__` it *must* be there. Just because `_a` starts with an underscore doesn't make it any better or worse than any other attribute, I would call it a "protected" attribute instead of a dummy attribute :). Are you sure you want to use `__slots__` at all, that seems to be the most "hacky" part of this whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. You just reference the property and use your setter in your init. Make your class follow the same rules internally that your users are expected to follow, at least when `__init__` is taking input like this.

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ['_a']
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, x):
        if len(x) == 10:
            self._a = x
        else:
            raise ValueError('incorrect length!')

    @a.deleter
    def a(self):
        self._a = ''
```

This way, if someone instantiates with an "incorrect length" they'll hit the same error path as setting object values.

You absolutely don't need the static method, that's a major use case of using setters in the first place, to validate or sanitize the data before accepting it! A reason to use a method like that is if you have multiple properties that all need the same scrubbing. e.g. Foo.b, Foo.c, Foo.d all work like Foo.a. In which case, you'd also want to indicate that it's private with a leading underscore: `def _validate_nums(x):`

For your new code, it's exactly the same as the old, no need for a static method:

```
class Foo(object):
    __slots__ = ('_a',)
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.a = x

    @property
    def a(self):
        return str(self._a)

    @a.setter
    def a(self, x):
        if x % 2 == 0:
            self._a = x
        else:
            raise ValueError(':(')

    @a.deleter
    def a(self):
        self._a = 0
```

A reason you might break from this is if you want an explicit undefined or default value, that your class normally prohibits (such as your original class prohibits any length that's not 10). In which case you could do:

```
        def __init__(self, a="four"):
            if a == "four":
                self._a = "four"
            else:
                self.a = a
```

This example is a little weird, you'd probably use `None`, `0`, an empty value (like `[]` or `()`), or something else to test against elsewhere, like you do with your newer code, which doesn't need this.

> It feels a little hacky to only put 'dummy' var names in **slots** (i.e., Foo._a only exists for the benefit of the Foo.a property), but it works.

I think you are looking at it backwards, but it makes sense since without directors we all would prefer to use `Foo.a` over `Foo._a`. However, `Foo._a` *is* your class attribute. It's what your class uses. It's the *property decorators* that allow `Foo.a` that are a little bit hacky. They are defensive measures to protect your class from misuse or bad behavior. They aren't your class attribute at all.

By also using `_a` instead of like `internal_data` you communicate to other users: `_a` is meant to be private, access it directly at your own risk, use the property decorators if you want expected behavior!